# cordova app running ok in browser but not in device

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I made an app with framework7 (used the framework7 template with Cordova) . when I test my app in browser it works fine but if I test it in emulator or as an apk in my device it gives my a blank screen with "requested content not found" as you can see in the picture (if I open the app it give me this page)

[image]

my config.xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>HelloCordova</name>
  <description>
  A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
  </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
  Apache Cordova Team    
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <!-- Allow links to example.com -->
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
   <!-- Wildcards are allowed for the protocol, as a prefix to the host, or as a suffix to the path -->
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <!-- A wildcard can be used to whitelist the entire network over HTTP and HTTPS.*NOT RECOMMENDED* -->
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
   <!-- The above is equivalent to these three declarations -->
   <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
   <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
   <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
  <platform name="android">
   <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
   <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
   <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
   </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using https request, even if it works with the browser it may not work with apk for several reasons.

When it occurred to me the reason was certificate for frontend secure URL had some issues. Certification authorities were not trusted.

So please check for https certificate is authorised with trusted chain of authorities.